# Code::Blocks, Fatal error: can't create obj/Debug/

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, codeblocks

Would anyone be kind to look at this log file and tell me what the mistake is. The problem only occurs when I compile from code :: blocks. Otherwise wxWidgets on that computer work great. OS is POP (20.04).
Build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Brisi (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-static-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -Wall -g  -c BrisiApp.cpp -o obj/Debug/BrisiApp.o
g++ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-static-3.1 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXGTK__ -pthread -Wall -g  -c BrisiMain.cpp -o obj/Debug/BrisiMain.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/Brisi obj/Debug/BrisiApp.o obj/Debug/BrisiMain.o  -L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_qa-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_html-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.a -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lX11 -lSM -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lXtst -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lwxtiff-3.1 -lwxjpeg-3.1 -lwxregexu-3.1 -lwxscintilla-3.1 -lexpat -lpng -lz -ldl -lm   
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create obj/Debug/BrisiApp.o: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
 
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create obj/Debug/BrisiMain.o: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

Of course I've already tried running code::blocks with "sudo" as well as assigning folder ownership to the user. The error is most likely somewhere in the code::blocks settings.

Comment: Did you try to create the wanted directory: `mkdir -p obj/Debug`?

Comment: Is the directory you are compiling in on a shared mount like a Windows SMB share or something similar?

Comment: Dear Michael Petch! Thank you for asking. The working folder is in the /home folder on the operating SSD.

Comment: Dear Mathieu! Thanks for the helpful suggestion i.e. for the help. It works! (In previous attempts, I only created the /obj, not the /obj/Debug folder. I don't know why this code :: blocks doesn't work automatically? Should it be set somewhere?) Certainly thank you!